# Running a .bat file using subprocess module and passing it input

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

Quick question on running a batch file using `subprocess` module in python.

#### Background

I'm running a `.bat` file from python and the .bat runs a windows application 100% (takes around a minute) and then waits for input from stdio (<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>) to close it.

What I'm doing is:

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\caSaira\Desktop\myExample.bat'], shell=True)
```

Since I wasn't sure on how to give <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I didn't do anything (was under assumption that this will be in waiting stage for input).
But, Looks like the windows application runs in an infinite loop.

#### Questions

1. Does anyone know how I can pass `'x'` letter, once I complete the execution?
2. Does anyone know why the application went in infinite loop instead of waiting stage?

Comment: What is waiting for input, code in the batch file or the Windows app it runs? Is there some reason you're running the latter via a batch file instead of directly (though `subprocess`)?

Comment: @martineau     Once the windows application completes its processing, it waits for user-input to close the application (Please enter x or ESC to close)

Comment: @martineau    There is no specific reason ... command prompt wasn't able to find the application I'm running as its a custom .exe fle/.. I thought  , I would cd to the exe location and then run the application... so  my batch file has only two lines of code ..  1) change directory to .exe location    2)  run the windows application with some command line arguments

Comment: If you specify the full path to the `.exe` — in either the batch file or when executing it directly with `subprocess` — it'll be found if it exists. You can also specify arguments to pass it via `subprocess` as well as use i/o redirection of `stdin` and/or `stdout` if desired.

Comment: I understand that .. but  'x' or ESC is not an input cmd line argument .. those are key inputs which needs to be entered once the process is completed.

Comment: subprocess.call('myfile.exe run test123') ....  this is my application with its corresponding CLI arguments ..... myFile.exe runs for some time , completes its execution and wait for a key press...

Comment: If I do , subprocess.call(['myFile.exe run test123' , 'x']) ...  Is this acceptable ? I thought  the second item in the list acts as a CLI argument

Comment: Sounds like the .exe isn't reading `stdin` when waiting for the input — there are OS-specific ways to directly check for and read keypresses — in which case I don't think you can do what you want either way. Does the .exe accept a command-line argument that tells it not to do this? If it does, that would provide a workaround.

Comment: @martineau  Not sure . I'm contacting the application developer if this thing can be removed completely. I'm using this application as part of my testbed  and trying to automate the tests.

Comment: Don't know what other constraints there might be, but I can assure you adding support for a command-line argument should be possible and would also be backwards-compatible with previous usage (something you can point out to developer).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally .. I have to use Popen and use the communicate function.

```
cmd1 = [r'myFile.bat']
p = SP.Popen(cmd1,stdin=SP.PIPE,stdout=SP.PIPE)
output = p.communicate(input='x'.encode())[0]
print(output.decode('ascii'))
```